# Oxid eShop event handlers

Tags: events, frameworks, handler, oxid

I am trying to create some tracking events on OXID eShop Framework on a custom module but I can't find any event handlers or something to put the code on some custom pages, without editing the core files. What I want is to make some custom API calls if I am on product page, category page, basket, etc. 
Is there any way I can handle this in a custom module?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. It would be cool if you would provide which class functionality you would like to change. There is a tutorial how to create oxid module, maybe it will be helpful for you: http://www.sitepoint.com/build-infinite-scroll-list-oxid-eshop-basics/

Comment: Oxid does not provide any events that you can hang onto (at least in version 4.x.x). You can however, extend Oxid without changing any of its files by writing custom modules. You might want to look up some tutorials on the web to get an idea of how it works. If you are looking for examples and patterns when building your own module I recommend you checking out the official PayPal Module that comes with Oxid or some of [these](https://github.com/OXIDCookbook) modules. Also check out the [metadata file](http://wiki.oxidforge.org/Features/Extension_metadata_file) to see what is actually possible.

Answer (score 2):

OXID has no such events or hooks you might know from magento or shopware. You have two options:

---

**1)** For running server side php code you need to extend OXID's functions, e.g. render() function for the pages you want to track.
For the product page it would be "details" -> applications/controllers/details.php
category page is "alist.php" and basket is basket.php

---

**2)** Make client side api calls with simple JS. You could appent all your js code to a tempalte block (e.g. in header oder footer) and create some if-else logic for different controller classes.
Like here: https://github.com/OXID-eSales/oxideshop_ce/blob/b-5.3-ce/source/application/views/azure/tpl/layout/base.tpl#L32

You could also have a look at any tracking module for google analytics or piwik, they are pretty similar to what you want to do.
I can give you more examples if you want.